# Is this a programming language?

Tags: assembly

I am trying some things with decompilacion and I get to have this:

[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhO91.png)

Can tell me if it is a programming language or what is it?

I do some research and i tink is assembler but im not shure

Comment: It's poetry. :) At least for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is object-oriented Pascal (e.g. Object Pascal, Borland Pascal) with inline assembly.